# Cross Domain windows authentication in Angular js application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

We have created an application and a web api which are hosted in various domains(or ports).  I want to integrated both windows authentication as well as Forms authentication. So I need logged in user name in the web api.

I have added header withCredentials in ajax post and i am not getting the username.  I have used HttpContext.Current.User to get the username.  But the same is working properly when the application and the webapi are hosted in the same port or same domain.

Can any one help me out??

Regards,
ganesh. k